# Include a parameter while invoking method through reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I found the following code:

```
try{ 
   Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
   Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
   Method expand = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
   expand.invoke(service);
 }
 catch(Exception ex){           

 }
```

and it works for expanding the status bar, but the method i want to access is not expand, its "disable"  and disable takes an int as a param.  can some tell me how to include a param when invoking a method in this fashion.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Hiding the status bar?

Comment: Please do not do this. There is no guarantee that this code will work on any existing Android device (as device manufacturers could change their implementation) or any future Android device (as Google could change their implementation or better secure this operation).

Comment: I am working with client who is insisting that we be able to run theor app in a kiosk mode.. they wont take no for an answer, so we are trying to find a way to block their customers from being able to access the system UI menu bar (ie. home, back, settings) on a samsung tab2 running 4.0.3   i know this is a bad ide and virtually impossible but none the less client wont accept

Comment: @erik I suggest you ask a new question explaining your exact goal and someone might come up with another way of achieving it without reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`invoke` takes extra parameters for arguments, so you can call it like this:

```
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
Method disable = statusbarManager.getMethod("disable", Integer.TYPE); //takes an int
disable.invoke(service, 2); //calls disable(2)
```

Note: as pointed out in the comments, this is a bad idea.